# How to add custom post type / post to Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, post, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called "books", how can I make "book" buyable through Woocommerce.I have tried the below code which have been mentioned all over the web.i hve edited the post type to book and my meta key is price.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',10,3);
function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price,$post){

    if ($post->$post->post_type === 'book')
    {
        $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", true);

}
return $price;
}
```

but the code dosent seem to run. The hook is not getting exexcuted rather the "$post" is not bringing up the id of custom post. it only brings in the products added via products of woocommerce. Am using woocommerce 3.0.7. Any help would be appreciated

is there any workaround fr this method

Comment: That code is out of date and doesn't work with WooCommerce 3.0. Reigel wrote a complete plugin called. [WooCommerce Custom Post Type Manager](http://reigelgallarde.me/product/woocommerce-woorei-cpt/) and it says it is updated to support WooCommerce 3.0.

Comment: That plugin is paid isnt it . Isnt there any workaround to attain the result instead of purchasing a plugin @helgatheking